# How do you best attribute errors in a Perl method to the caller

Tags: perl, error-handling

Given a method that may fail with warnings and/or errors, I want the error method to show up at the caller. Fir instance this script:

```
foo(0);         # line 1

sub foo {
    1 / shift;  # line 4
}
```

Produces the error `Illegal division by zero at foo.pl line 4`, but I want `Illegal division by zero at foo.pl line 1`. There should be several ways if I put the method in a module or if I wrap the method body in eval, but I have not found an easy way like this:

```
sub foo {
    attributeErrorsToCaller; # do some magic
    1 / shift;
}
```

Is there such a way?

---

**EDIT:** [mirod's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339816/how-do-you-best-attribute-errors-in-a-perl-method-to-the-caller/6340348#6340348) comes close not what I was looking for:

```
Foo::foo(0);         # line 1

package Foo;
use diagnostics -traceonly;
BEGIN { disable diagnostics; }

sub foo {
    enable diagnostics;
    1 / shift;       # line 9
}
```

Without `enable diagnostics` the error message is `Illegal division by zero at foo.pl line 9.`. With `enable diagnostics` it is still too verbose, but this may also be useful:

```
Uncaught exception from user code:
    Illegal division by zero at foo.pl line 10.
 at foo.pl line 10
     Foo::foo(0) called at foo.pl line 2
```

I bet I could [hack diagnostics](http://search.metacpan.org/#/showsrc/diagnostics) to get exactely the feature I want, but using diagnostics as raw module is probably more recommended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would `use diagnostics;` be enough for you? It will dump the call stack, so the caller is quite easy to find out.

For example in you example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;


foo(0);

sub foo
  { 
    return 1/$_[0];
  }
```

gives this:

```
`Illegal division by zero at test_die line 12 (#1)
    (F) You tried to divide a number by 0.  Either something was wrong in
    your logic, or you need to put a conditional in to guard against
    meaningless input.

Uncaught exception from user code:
        Illegal division by zero at test_die line 12.
 at test_die line 12
        main::foo(0) called at test_die line 8
```

Comment: If you can enable diagnostics for particular functions (or modules) and limits it output to all but "main::foo(0) called at test_die line 8", that's what I am looking for.

Comment: a quick look at the docs (`man diagnostics` or `perldoc diagnostics`) shows that you can use `enable diagnostics` and `disable diagnostics` to turn on or off diagnostics. Would that work?

Comment: `diagnostics` is not enough, but it comes close enough and shows how I could implement a full solution.

Answer (score 10):

[Carp](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.0/lib/Carp.pm) is very, very close to "do_some_magic" you are asking for. For instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 
use strict;

# I fork to be as close to natural die() as possible. 
fork() or Foo::foo();
fork() or Foo::bar();
fork() or Foo::baz();
sleep 1;

package Foo;
use Carp; 

sub foo { die "Some error (foo)"; }; 
sub bar { croak "Some error (bar)"; }; 
sub baz { bar(); };
```

As you can see, `croak()` acts almost like `die()`, but reports error to the caller (even indirectly -- see baz).

However, it won't handle 1/0 for you -- either use `eval` (or even [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Try-Tiny-0.09/lib/Try/Tiny.pm)), or check input values* and say "division by zero" yourself.

`Carp` is standard, which means **understandable by further maintainers of your code**, and also can print neat stack traces via `confess` or `cluck` or even `print Carp::longmess` (see the doc).

**which is good anyway*

Comment: Thanks for explaining Carp. I guess for most use cases this is enough. But as you also said, this does neither catch 1/0 nor existing calls of `die()`, so I must foresee where in sub foo errors might by thrown. I thought there is some trick with `$SIG{__DIE__}` or wrapping the whole function with `eval` and `Devel::StackTrace`, but I have not found the exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not like you describe. You can implement Debug::Trace to pull off a full back trace.

You may also find the perl `caller` which is quite useful for this type of debugging. But for a live application you will likely need to do more detailed tracing.

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html

Comment: Sounded like he wanted something custom made.